# CodeIgniter - displaying view based on variable from database

Tags: database, codeigniter, if-statement, view

I've been learning codeigniter recently and trying to push an application out. im running into problems with the if else statements displaying views. i am trying to pull `in_party` from  the database`ci_admin_info` and display views depending if its set to 1 or 0. its bypassing any condition and just displaying the first view set.

> Model

```
function get_in_par(){
        
        $this->db->select('in_party');
        $this->db->from('ci_admin_info');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $ret = $query->row();
        return $ret->in_party;
        
            
    }
```

> Controller

```
public function index(){

        $data['title'] = 'Party';
        $data['party'] = $this->party_model->get_party();
        $data['prov'] = $this->party_model->get_prov_name();
        $data['info'] = $this->party_model->get_all();
        $data['res'] = $this->party_model->get_party_res();
        $data['rank'] = $this->party_model->get_pa_rank();


        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
        
        
        
        $inpar = $this->party_model->get_in_par();
        
        if(isset($inpar['in_party'])==0){
            
        $this->load->view('admin/party/join');
            
        } else {
            
        $this->load->view('admin/party/index'); 
        
        }

        $this->load->view('admin/includes/_footer');

    }
```

I've tried rearranging it into the parent construct as well and it just bypassed it completely. just trying to make it load the join view if `in_party` = 0 . i've tried without isset bypasses it as well. i've tried switch but don't think it registered that as well. i think i'm missing something in my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
      ->from('ci_admin_info')
      ->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result[0];
```

```
$inpar = $this->party_model->get_in_par();        
if(!isset($inpar['in_party']) || $inpar['in_party']=="0"){....
```

Comment: what would be the appropriate way to do this? ive tried `result_array` `row_array` ive taken out return value, but still cant receive if it is displaying 0 or 1, how would i set up the module and controller to read this? im still learning

Comment: ive tried this, but it points to index even when the value is 0.

Comment: Oh, so here's the thing. isset() checks if the variable is undefined Or null. But it gives true even if the value of variable is 0. I've updated the answer. Check it once.

Comment: it still shows index with a value of 0. would there be a way to verify on null? if null, that display join? or would changing values to TRUE or FALSE prove better?

Comment: Do this, var_dump($inpar);  var_dump(!isset($inpar['in_party'])); and paste the output here.

Comment: ay(8) { ["admin_id"]=> string(2) "31" ["p_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["state_name"]=> string(9) "Purgatory" ["n_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["nation_name"]=> string(3) "USA" ["title"]=> string(6) "Leader" ["in_party"]=> string(1) "1" ["pa_id"]=> string(1) "1" } bool(false)

Comment: The type of the in_party is string and we're comparing with integer. Try it again by changing 0 to "0" In the if condition, and let me know here. And do the var dump for the case where the value is 0, that way we can see if it still gives "0" Or 0.

Comment: i actually noticed somethng wrong in that line. im using a user with admin id 37, but its reading the id of 31. im trying to dive into my code to see why its pulling the admin id of 31 and not 37

Comment: Okay, but did you try it with "0" instead of 0 ?

Comment: "in_party"]=> string(1) "0" } bool(false) array(1) { ["in_party"]=> string(1) "0" } bool(false)

Comment: Okay, so replace 0 with "0" in your if condition, and then it's done.

Comment: i actually think i have to redo the entire thing. no matter what i try, its not pulling information from the right user.